# 2 cubes collide and fall in water, how to get one?

Tags: portal-2

Been stuck on this level for awhile.

It has one turret out of reach, and a light wall coming down from the ceiling, also a lazer coming down from the ceiling.

Pressing a button launches two cubes that get launched and collide and fall into the water below.

I know I need to get the cube, but I haven't figured out how.

**Don't solve the entire level, just how to get the cube please!**

Comment: What test chamber is this?

Comment: @splatteredbits Chapter 4 Test Chamber 18
http://theportalwiki.com/wiki/Portal_2_Chapter_4_Test_Chamber_18
Wiki contains spoilers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember this one, The way to get the cube is to block off one of the cube's pathways with the light bridge.  Hopefully that's enough information to get you where you need to be, without solving it.  Good Luck!